# Which one should I use certmanager.k8s.io or certmanager.io in OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, cert-manager

I am trying user cert-manager to manage certificate in OpenShift, but I saw some examples used apiVersion: cert-manager.io, some examples used apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io.

I check them in my OpenShift, seems there is only certmanager.k8s.io, even though I have installed the latest cer-manager.

```
# oc get crd | grep certmanager.k8s.io
certificates.certmanager.k8s.io                             2020-01-07T17:27:09Z
challenges.certmanager.k8s.io                               2020-01-07T17:27:10Z
clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io                           2020-01-07T17:27:08Z
issuers.certmanager.k8s.io                                  2020-01-07T17:27:09Z
orders.certmanager.k8s.io                                   2020-01-07T17:27:09Z
```

I am confused, what difference for them? Which one should I use? Thanks your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Due to new policies in the upstream Kubernetes project, we have renamed the
>   API group from certmanager.k8s.io to cert-manager.io.[renamed-api-group](https://cert-manager.io/docs/release-notes/release-notes-0.11/#renamed-api-group)

Here is the upstream k8s KEP [K8s group-protection](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-api-machinery/20190612-crd-group-protection.md)

You should use `cert-manager.io` api group in the yaml.

Comment: Hi @Suresh Vishnoi, but I have not see any cert-manager.io resource  via command "oc get crd", do I need to take action to upgrade to  cert-manager.io? In fact I installed V0.13, it is the latest version, it should have defined cert-manager.io resource, but I didn't see it. Any ideas for that?

Comment: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/master/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml  it seems all of the crds are using cert-manager.io

Comment: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.13.0/cert-manager-openshift.yaml , this one also

Comment: you can redeploy it with `oc apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v0.13.0/cert-manager-openshift.yaml`

Comment: After Re-deploy, now I can see cert-manager.io, that's great.

Comment: However, I saw a few of errors when I create certificate. ``` E0123 21:09:23.156506       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="[pods \"cm-acme-http-solver-tf5s8\" is forbidden: cannot set blockOwnerDeletion in this case because cannot find RESTMapping for APIVersion cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 Kind Challenge: no matches for kind \"Challenge\" in version \"cert-manager.io/v1alpha2\", services \"cm-acme-http-solver-sqd7v\" is forbidden: cannot set blockOwnerDeletion in this case because cannot find ```

Comment: yea, there is a github issue for the same situation https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2475

Comment: Thanks @Suresh Vishnoi, it helps, I will go through that link.